# Protect Jenkins build from clean up via api

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to protect some Jenkins builds from the auto cleanup. I have found the http://ci.jenkins.com/job/[job_name]/[build_v]/toggleLogKeep however this requires me to check the state. Are there any other end points I can use. Ideally it would be /keepBuildForever /dontKeepBuildForever

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no good solution. The best way is to list all keep forever builds. Then check if it is already in the list, if not hit the /toggleLogKeep endpoint

```
buildsXml = http://ci.jenkins.com/api/xml?depth=2&xpath=/hudson/job/build[keepLog=%22true%22]/url&wrapper=forever
#check if your build is in buildsXml
```

Answer (score 0):

After accidently deleting an important build, I found this alternative solution:

```
# if running inside a job, the following vars are already populated:
#JOB_NAME=yourjobname
#BUILD_NUMBER=123  #your build number
#JENKINS_HOST=192.168.1.11
#JENKINS_PORT=8080
#JENKINS_URL=http://${JENKINS_HOST}:${JENKINS_PORT}

wget --no-check-certificate "${JENKINS_URL}/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar"

java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s "$JENKINS_URL" keep-build "$JOB_NAME" "$BUILD_NUMBER"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done a gist for this

https://gist.github.com/antonio-quarta/357e4391573a503b9c494ab5109e238b

```
import requests
import os

BUILD_URL = "https://<jenkinsurl>/job/<jobname>/<buildid>/"

JENKINS_USER = "user"

JENKINS_API_TOKEN = os.environ["JENKINS_API_TOKEN"]
toggle_keep_url = BUILD_URL+'toggleLogKeep'

r = requests.post(toggle_keep_url, auth=(JENKINS_USER,JENKINS_API_TOKEN),)
print(r.status_code)
```